# TinyMCE Code cleanup?

Tags: jquery, tinymce

TinyMCE is neat, there is no disputing that.  However, I have found that the HTML it generates leaves much to be desired.  For instance, when one selects text and changes colors it injects a pleathora of   tags - unrequired at best of times but enough to confuse TinyMCE in many instances.

My question - is there a TinyMCE plugin that can cleanup the HTML it generates?  A brief search on Google has not yielded anything too useful.

Comment: Not sure for tinyMCE but I know ckeditor has one. I used to work with tinyMCE but now that I tried ckeditor I will ever go back!

Comment: Hmm... I doubt that I have the option of switching to something else in the short term.

Comment: Have to agree with you, ComputerArts.  I rue the decision to go with tinyMCE.  The HTML it produces is quite simply garbage.  I have to live with it for now.